# Use filter to remove list items in AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

In an AngularJS template I can *sort* the elements in a `select` list using filter `|` notation:

```
<select ng-model="myListModel" 
        ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in myList | orderBy:'name' }">
```

Equivalently it seems I can perform the sorting in the controller using `$filter`:

```
$scope.myList = $filter('orderBy')($scope.myList,'name');
```

Now, I can *remove* elements from a list in the template using:

```
<select ng-model="myListModel"
        ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in myList | filter: { id : '!' + $scope.someId }">
```

But how can I (analogously with the sorting example) perform the same removal in the controller using `$filter` (thereby avoiding lots of JavaScript code to perform the removal)?

Comment: Something like `$scope.filteredList = $filter("filter")($scope.myList, { id: "!" + $scope.someId });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code. It makes use of the `filter` filter and note that not equals is implemented using `!` and a string representation of your ID to remove.

```
$scope.filteredListToUseInTemplate = 
     $filter("filter")($scope.myList, { id: "!" + $scope.someId });
```

Then use `filteredListToUseInTemplate` in your template instead of `myList`.

Comment: @devqon: Because this is [explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) by StackOverflow. It's nice to share the solution of difficult problems with others, plus it's a good way to "store" the solution for yourself for later reference.

Comment: Why are you creating a `filteredList` array? Just do `$scope.filteredListToUseInTemplate = $filter("filter")($scope.myList, { id: "!" + $scope.someId });`